# Populating ListView from DataTable

Tags: c#, android, datatable, android-listview, monodevelop

I fired a database query and got result in a `DataTable`.
When I used following sample code, I'm able to retrieve all values from `DataTable` :

```
    private void LoadList(DataTable res)
    {
            foreach(DataRow row in res.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
    }
```

How this `DataTable` can be **dynamically** passed to `ListView`  in order to display all the elements of `DataTable`?

Is there any other alternative to `ListView` to display data from DataTable?

I'm absolute beginner when it comes to using *Mono for Android*, so **any help appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using databases, the common way is to use a ContentProvider, get a Cursor and then populate a SimpleCursorAdapter (and even a ViewBinder if you want some customization)

Unless there is a good reason not to use them, I'll stick to the tools recommended by the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
listView.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dynamic or customize ListView 
see the example given [here](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html)

This may help you.